# Logic Issues with paypal SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated PayPal SDK with sandbox account.It's for my website with custom packages name and their prices. like Basic package $79, Pro Package $150, and professional $400. Once the user clicks on the proceed button it redirects to PayPal with the basic package and $79 price.For other packages What logic I have to do?

I have tried to insert an array ($basic, $pro, $professional) into item object its fine but Setprice() it doesn't accept an array.

I'm just stuck with it enter code here it even I didn't know how to ask question Extremely Sorry.

Here is my checkout.php

```
    if ($_POST) {

        $priceBasic= (is_numeric($_POST['b']) ? (int)$_POST['b'] : 89); 
        $pkgBasic = $_POST['basic'];

        $pricePro= (is_numeric($_POST['p']) ? (int)$_POST['p'] : 175);  
        $pkgPro = $_POST['pro'];

        $priceUltra= (is_numeric($_POST['u']) ? (int)$_POST['u'] : 449);    
        $pkgUltra = $_POST['ultra'];

        $shipping = 0.0;
        $total = $priceBasic + $shipping;

        //PAYER INSTANT
         $payer = new Payer();
         $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        // DEFINING ITEMS

        // $packages = [$pkgBasic, $pkgPro, $pkgUltra];
        // $price = [$priceBasic, $pricePro, $priceUltra];

        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName($packages)->setCurrency('USD')->setQuantity(1)-
        >setPrice($priceBasic);

        //PACKAGES LIST
        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item]);

         $details = new Details();
         $details->setShipping($shipping)
        ->setSubTotal($total);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')->setTotal($total)
        ->setDetails($details);
        $transaction = new Transaction();

        $transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)-
        >setDescription('Hello Hash Thanks for first paypal')-
        >setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=true')
        ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=false');


        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale')->setPayer($payer)
       ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)->setTransactions([$transaction]);


       try {
         $payment->create($paypal);
       } catch (Exception $e) {

       die($e);

     }

     $aprovalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

     // echo $aprovalUrl;
     header("location:".$aprovalUrl);

  }

?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case to switch between prices. Hope this helps.

```
$package_type = $_POST['package_type'];

switch($package_type) {
    case "basic":
        $price = 89;
    break;
    case "pro":
        $price = 175;
    break;
    case "ultra":
        $price = 449;
    break;
}


$shipping = 0.0;
$total = $priceBasic + $shipping;

//PAYER INSTANT
 $payer = new Payer();
 $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

// DEFINING ITEMS

// $packages = [$pkgBasic, $pkgPro, $pkgUltra];
// $price = [$priceBasic, $pricePro, $priceUltra];

$item = new Item();
$item->setName($packages)->setCurrency('USD')->setQuantity(1)-
>setPrice($price);


//PACKAGES LIST
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);

 $details = new Details();
 $details->setShipping($shipping)
->setSubTotal($total);


$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')->setTotal($total)
->setDetails($details);
$transaction = new Transaction();

 $transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)-
 >setDescription('Hello Hash Thanks for first paypal')-
 >setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

 $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
 $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=true')
 ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=false');


 $payment = new Payment();
 $payment->setIntent('sale')->setPayer($payer)
->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)->setTransactions([$transaction]);


try {
$payment->create($paypal);
} catch (Exception $e) {

die($e);

}

  $aprovalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

// echo $aprovalUrl;
header("location:".$aprovalUrl);

?>
```

Switch case example, Check whether this code is working for you. This is how you have to switch the price according to the plan.

```
<?php
$package_type = 'pro';
$price = 0;

switch($package_type) {
    case "basic":
        echo 'hai';
    break;
    case "pro":
        $price = 175;
    break;
    case "ultra":
        $price = 449;
    break;
}
echo $price;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sundar I made it through in_array function its works but I'm still on it. I got this errror  `400{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"913012b67b041"}`

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm beginner

Comment: I have tired through your code but `$price` within switch not getting any value please help would be greatfull

Comment: Buddy I'm looking forward to hear from you

Comment: What is the issue ua are having now? Its just a switch. Just have some reading on switch in php